# GStreamer caps filtering issue when converting from command line to C code

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am having issues converting my working GStreamer pipeline from a command line version to C code. From the command line the following command will successfully play my headerless mu-law audio file:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=test.ulaw ! audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1 ! mulawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

However, my issues are arising when trying to add in the "audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1" bit into my C program. The program started off playing wav files (using wavparse in place of mulawdec) so that I know my base C code works, and it must just be that I am misinterpreting how the caps bit needs to be added in to make it work with mu-law files.

I am creating the caps, then using the gst_element_link_filtered to use this:

```
GstCaps *gstMuLawCaps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1");
gst_element_link_filtered(gstFileSource, gstMuLawDecoder, gstMuLawCaps);
```

But this is not working, and running the program produces the following output:

```
>gst-mulaw.exe test.ulaw
Playing.
Error: Internal data flow error.
Playback Finished.
```

I would be grateful if anyone is able to help shed some light on what I am doing wrong. The full code is given below:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>

static gboolean bus_call (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data) {
  GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("End of stream\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      gchar  *debug;
      GError *error;
      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_free (debug);
      g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

static void on_pad_added (GstElement *gstSourceElement, GstPad *gstSourcePad, gpointer data) {
  g_print("Linking dynamic pad.\n");

  GstPad *gstSinkPad;
  GstElement *gstSinkElement = (GstElement *) data;

  gstSinkPad = gst_element_get_static_pad (gstSinkElement, "sink");
  gst_pad_link (gstSourcePad, gstSinkPad);
  gst_object_unref (gstSinkPad);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstElement *gstPipeline, *gstFileSource, *gstMuLawDecoder, *gstAudioConvert, *gstAudioResample, *gstAudioSink;
  GstBus *bus;

  // GStreamer initialisation.
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  // Check input arguments.
  if (argc != 2) {
    g_printerr ("Usage: %s <mu-law File>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  // Create the GStreamer elements.
  gstPipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("player");
  gstFileSource = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "filesource");
  gstMuLawDecoder = gst_element_factory_make ("mulawdec", "mulawdecoder");
  gstAudioConvert = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert", "audioconverter");
  gstAudioResample = gst_element_factory_make ("audioresample", "audioresampler");
  gstAudioSink = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audiosink");

  if (!gstPipeline || !gstFileSource || !gstMuLawDecoder || !gstAudioConvert || !gstAudioResample || !gstAudioSink) {
    g_printerr ("An element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Linke the filesrc object to that passed on the command line.
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (gstFileSource), "location", argv[1], NULL);

  // Setup the GStreamer bus.
  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (gstPipeline));
  gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  // Add the objects to the pipeline.
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (gstPipeline), gstFileSource, gstMuLawDecoder, gstAudioConvert, gstAudioResample, gstAudioSink, NULL);

  // Link the elements together.
  GstCaps *gstMuLawCaps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1");
  gst_element_link_filtered(gstFileSource, gstMuLawDecoder, gstMuLawCaps);
  gst_caps_unref(gstMuLawCaps);
  gst_element_link_many (gstAudioConvert, gstAudioResample, gstAudioSink, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (gstMuLawDecoder, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), gstAudioConvert);

  // Set the pipeline to state playing, and run the main loop.
  g_print ("Playing.\n");
  gst_element_set_state (gstPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  // Finished playback, cleanup.
  g_print ("Playback Finished.\n");
  gst_element_set_state (gstPipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (gstPipeline));
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
  // Link the elements together.
  GstCaps *gstMuLawCaps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1");
  gst_element_link_filtered(gstFileSource, gstMuLawDecoder, gstMuLawCaps);
  gst_caps_unref(gstMuLawCaps);
  gst_element_link_many (gstAudioConvert, gstAudioResample, gstAudioSink, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (gstMuLawDecoder, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), gstAudioConvert);
```

to

```
  // Link the elements together.
  GstCaps *gstMuLawCaps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1");
  gst_element_link_filtered(gstFileSource, gstMuLawDecoder, gstMuLawCaps);
  gst_caps_unref(gstMuLawCaps);
  gst_element_link_many (gstMuLawDecoder, gstAudioConvert, gstAudioResample, gstAudioSink, NULL);
```

pad-added handling is needed for elements with sometimes pads (e.g. demuxers). You can remove the on_pad_added callback function (it was not called anyway, right?) The pad-type can be see in "gst-inspect mulawdec" output.

Comment: Excellent, thank-you for your response that has solved my issues. I hadn't thought to check for the availability of the pads using gst-inspect, nor checking pad_added was actually called.